# unable to preview Attachments as an image on public site

Tags: visualforce, attachment, images, site.com

I have created a visualforce page and hosted it on a public site. I am showing contact and account attachments as images.
When I try to preview it using developer console, it is showing the images, but when I am trying to see on public site images are not visible. just a small icon of invalid image is visible.

to display an image I am using this tag with URL similar to this

> <apex:outputPanel >
> <apex:image style="padding-right: 2px;" url="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!companyLogoId}" alt="Logo" width="175"/>
> </apex:outputPanel>

The user profile has all the access.

Comment: From Site's "Public Access Settings" we need to set permissions to the Parent object which is associated to the attachment

Comment: How to give permisions?